# About the bookmarks/questions /answers of this mathstack user in chem stack exchange

Tags: discussion, support, bookmarks

I dont know how to search and seems like no result is shown of this specific user whose account was deleted today , can anyone help ? Here is the mathstack google cache of the user : https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://math.stackexchange.com/users/900638/waybig?tab=profile

Comment: I fail to see what is being asked. What is the question, exactly?

Comment: I want to see his all questions / answers and bookmarks as it was my bro account

Comment: By "his", you mean "my"? This account was merged into *your* current account, the very account from which you are posting this question.

Comment: Exactly Sir , as there was no email of what happened /when deleted/when merged etc therefore i was comfused totally

Comment: And i want to know if all the bookmarks r there or some r lost / all questions/answers etc

Comment: Well, the questions and answers will now all be on *your* own profile. I don't know about bookmarks.

Comment: Thats why wanted to see the Waybig account all question answers bookmarks in Physics and Chem stack exchange

Comment: I see thats a relief for question amd answers .Sir but still i am worried about the bookmarks bc it was kinda precious to me thats whh asking

Comment: You seem to care a lot about your brother's bookmarks.

Comment: I am able to see the mathstack bookmarks but not of physics and chem ones hence asked the question

Comment: Yes Sir bc it was precious to him and kinda to me too bc he marks nice questions /doubts and i already send several mails regarding this issue , and no reply came from their side hence asked here in meta .

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that; I can barely see anything about a deleted user, let alone any details about which exact posts they have bookmarked. You might find them transferred to your current account, or you might not. I don't know how the system works. My suggestion for the future is to stick to using one account and don't look for a second account to upvote yourself. Then you won't run into any such issues.

Comment: Yes Sir definitely i already said this that it will not happen in future in mod mails and the email too . But just in case if we want to see any user bookmarks how to see it can u tell the steps ? Like in math stack exchange someone told me about database thing but dont know how we can use that to see the questions /bookmarks of other users .

Comment: Just put that as answer to my query Sir that will suffice my query in  all ways.( SEDE thing how to use it )

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it provides nothing of value.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Not quite, this question reminded me I have to stop using website's bookmarks and switch to local ones in a browser:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This account was merged into yours for reasons that the Mathematics moderators will be aware of.

The questions and answers will have all been transferred to your account, although some of them are deleted.

The bookmarks may be found (for now) using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/1254771/questions-bookmarked-or-commented-on-by-user). The now-deleted account has the user ID 106350.

Comment: "Some of them r deleted" u meant Sir the ones who gave answers to those problems will lose their reputation too ? And whats the SEDE query link to all questions of that user ?

Comment: Any of them that were deleted before this (you deleted some of them yourself) will remain deleted now.

Comment: You can go and look for an appropriate SEDE query yourself, although I'm not sure if it can view deleted posts. All the non-deleted ones are visible from *your own profile* anyway.

Comment: Yeah Sir i will , was there some discussion happened anywhere how to use the SEDE query? Details i meant for any specific thing a user wants to know

Comment: Enter the appropriate user id and click run query. Is there some problem with that?

Comment: Also, please stop calling me Sir. I'm not a knight, nor am I whomever you call Sir in your daily life.

Comment: Oh very sry for calling u that , i was just used to it.  And yeah i clicked on compose query , what to write in title and description so as to run that query ?

Comment: You are a knight in shining armour or just a teacher.. you can choose ;D

Comment: @wizardmath enter the user ID given above and hit run query at the bottom..

Comment: Safdar i am not asking about the one sent by orthocresol one , i  am asking in general for a query we have and we want to run the query to get the results

Comment: The above one sent by orthocresol just gives the bookmarks ones , so i asked for general other stuff

Comment: Can we move this convo to chat @WizardMath? topic seems to be unrelated to the actual answer

Comment: @SafdarFaisal please don't jump on the bandwagon to move everything to chat. I don't even see much benefit in the question and answer in the first place and I don't think this needs to be copied and preserved another way. This whole thing is something for the site support and not really for meta. I doubt it will be useful for anyone else.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン i just wanted to stop the convo from pinging ortho cresol as it had nothing to do with his original answer.. Move convo to chat meant moving the rest of the convo to a chat room that I use..